# combine two dataframes of unequal size and based on conditions

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2. I want to take the values of a column in df2 and add it to df1.

df1:

```
Title = ['Aeroplane', 'Ships', 'Houses']
Term = ['Computers', 'Flasks', 'Mouse']
counts_1 = [200, 30, 45, 66, 33, 450, 60, 100, 150]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"Title": Title, "Terms": Term})
product_terms = product(term_list, cap_list)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(product_terms, columns=['Term', 'Title'])
df_1['C1'] = counts_1

       Term        Title       C1
    0  Computers   Aeroplane   200
    1  Computers   Ships        30
    2  Computers   Houses       45
    3  Flasks      Aeroplane    66
    4  Flasks      Ships        33
    5  Flasks      Houses      450
    6  Mouse      Aeroplane     60
    7  Mouse      Ships        100
    8  Mouse      Houses       150
```

df2 (smaller one)

```
terms = ['Computers', 'Flasks', 'Flasks', 'Mouse']
title = ['Aeroplane', 'Aeroplane', 'Ships', 'Houses']
count_2 = [3, 6, 13, 15]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Term': terms, 'Title': title, 'C2': count_2})


       Term        Title       C2
    0  Computers   Aeroplane    3
    1  Flasks      Aeroplane    6
    2  Flasks      Ships       13
    3  Mouse      Houses       15
```

I want to combine the two dfs into one df like below: add the column C2 from df_2 to df_1 (based on the Term and Title col match) and insert 0 where ever there is no corresponding matching Term and Title cols.

```
   Term        Title       C1      C2
0  Computers   Aeroplane   200      3
1  Computers   Ships        30      0
2  Computers   Houses       45      0
3  Flasks      Aeroplane    66      6
4  Flasks      Ships        33     13
5  Flasks      Houses      450      0
6  Mouse      Aeroplane     60      0
7  Mouse      Ships        100     15
8  Mouse      Houses       150      0
```

df2's terms and titles are always a subset of those in df1.

Here is what I tried:

```
df_1.set_index(['Term', 'Title'], inplace=True)
df_2.set_index(['Term', 'Title'], inplace=True)
```

Then, iterate over the rows and assign values.

```
for idx, row in df_1.iterrows():
    try:
        c2_value = df_2.loc[idx, 'C2']
    except:
        df_1.loc[idx, 'C2'] = 0
    else:
        df_1.loc[idx]['C2'] = c2_value


df_final = df_1.reset_index()
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I want? I feel `iterrows` may not be an efficient way. My dataframes have millions of rows.

Comment: the dataframe 1 isnt reproducible, please edit the question to it be reproducible

Comment: `pd.merge(df_1,df_2,on=['Term','Title'],how='outer').fillna(0)` replicates your expected output? can you test - if it's correct then we can close as a duplicate

Comment: Perfect! pd.merge works